# Tried Everything Cant find Nodes in Node Editor

Tags: texturing, node-editor

[image]

I've tried numpad . I've tried ctrl+f nothing seems to work and I cant for the life of my find the damn nodes in the node editor. I'm using a macbook btw, so maybe the problem is that my numpad . isnt beside the 0?

Answer (score 2):

You have to check *Use Nodes* otherwise no nodes will be displayed.

[image]

Then if still not visible, position all nodes in your view by pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> (it may also be labeled <kbd>pos1</kbd> on your keyboard).

Comment: Thanks so much this is a lifesaver the only thing though is I can't seem to find the Use Nodes button for the texture nodes?